# Multiply rows of a column in different chunk of data, add them together and get the average?

Tags: awk

I have a chunk of data that looks like this:

```
924
777 777 777 8445.65349
P 9.44657 -0.840283 -0.394467
C 4.0555 -0.683104 -1.70917
P 7.5169 3.54172 2.77681
C 3.21536 2.67146 2.20242
P 4.33641 7.62012 6.10004
C 0.851002 3.61045 5.6153
P -0.884031 7.93847 9.1465
```

and this continues until another chunk starts:

```
C -2.60284 -2.72416 5.53391
P -7.1821 -5.0307 2.45961
C -4.15764 -0.916509 2.41971
P -7.95623 -0.58521 -2.00452
C -3.06671 0.655337 -1.24124    <-- (here is the end of first chunk)
924                             <-- (here another section starts)
777 777 777 8175.13598
P 9.77168 -2.01085 -0.577195
C 5.1768 -1.76539 -1.75107
P 7.16094 2.89923 2.55963
C 2.93574 1.47131 2.21471
P 3.93407 7.32403 5.62331
```

I want to multiply the entries of each row which begins with `P` to the next `P` (in a consecutive way) and add them together and take the average.

For example:

If this is the first P (P 9.44657 -0.840283 -0.394467) and this is the second P (P 7.5169 3.54172 2.77681), do ... (9.44657×7.5169) + (-0.840×3.541) + (-0.394×2.77) ... and repeat it for second P and third P, and so on ... then add them and get the average, and do this for many chunks of data which follow the same pattern.

Is it possible to do this with `awk`?

Answer (score 0):

The following helps you to reseive sum of production all elements of the line which starts from `P` and its quantity.

```
awk '/^P/{for (n=2;n<=NF;n++){sum+=arr[n]*$n;arr[n]=$n;t++}} END{print sum t}'
```

I am not clear understood what do you mean under `chunks` but if you want to receive sum not for file in total but for separate piece you are free to modify program as follow

```
awk '/^924$/ && sum != 0 {print sum t; sum=0; t=0} \
     /^P/{for (n=2;n<=NF;n++){sum+=arr[n]*$n;arr[n]=$n;t++}} \
     END{print sum t}'
```

Comment: Thanks Costas.Can I ask another question concerning a different calculation on this data?

Comment: I want to to subtract P1 from P2 and P2 from P3 and then multiply them and then repeat this for (P2 - P3) * (P3 -P4) and so on till the end of the file and take the average and do this for all sections of the file.

Comment: @amir What do you mean about P**1** : is it first number in first P-line and P**4** - first number in second P-line? Do you wants to do it with all file or section by section? What do you mean under "average" (please supply with formula)?

Comment: and do this calculation for (P1 - P3) * (P3 -P5) ....untill the end of the file and repeat it for (P1 - P4) *(P4 - P7) ...and (P1 - P5) * (P5 - P9) ...the aim is to get a damped sinosidal corr function.Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: if P1(9.44657 -0.840283 -0.394467) and P2( 7.5169 3.54172 2.77681) I want to do (9.44 - 7.51, -0.84 - 3.54, -0.39 - 2.77) ...and then do this for P2 from P3 ...and then multiply these two and repeat it for the whole file and take the average with regard to the number of Ps in the section of file. then I want do all these calculations for (P1 - P3) * (P3 -P5) ...and (P1 - P4) * (P4 - P7) ...I want to do these calculations for different sections of the file which follow the same pattern.I hope this elaborate the problem.Thanks for your time.

Comment: You have 3 numbers in line (P1.1,P1.2,P1.3). When you substact corresponded 3s (P2.1,P2.2,P2.3) whith the first 3s you will receive 3 numbers too. Explaine what you intend to multiply?

Comment: assume that P1(1 2 3) and P2(4 5 6) when subtract them we get (-3 -3 -3) and then P2(4 5 6) from P3(7 8 9) we get(-3 -3 -3) and then multiply these two together (3 3 3) * (3 3 3) and add, which gives 27.by P1 I mean P at line one the P2 at line three and so on.

Comment: @amir How you receive 27 ? (-3+-3+-3)*(-3+-3+-3)?

Comment: so these are vector coordinates ...after subtraction we get two new vectors each with three components ..(3 3 3) and (3 3 3) ...x=3, y=3, z=3 ...and then multiply each component of each vector and add them together ..so like this (3*3 + 3*3 + 3*3) which gives 27.

Comment: Try to check `awk '/^P/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){s+=d[i]*(l[i]-$i);if(l[i]!="")d[i]=l[i]-$i;l[i]=$i};if(s!=0){t++;sum=+s}}END{print sum/t}'` for 1 chunk

Comment: I receive the following error:                                                     awk: cmd. line:1: /^P/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){s+=d[i]*(l[i]-$i);if(l[i]!="")d[i]=l[i]-$i;l[i]=$i};if(‌​s!=0){t++;sum=+s}}END{print sum/t}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                ^ invalid char '�' in expression
awk: cmd. line:1: /^P/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){s+=d[i]*(l[i]-$i);if(l[i]!="")d[i]=l[i]-$i;l[i]=$i};if(‌​s!=0){t++;sum=+s}}END{print sum/t}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                ^ syntax error

Comment: It may be some unveiwable chars when copy|paste from http; I have checked `awk '/^P/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){s+=d[i]*(l[i]-$i);if(l[i]!="")d[i]=l[i]-$i;l[i]=$i};if(s!=0){t++;sum=+s}}END{print (sum/t)}'`

Comment: awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){s+=d[i]*(l[i]-$i);if(l[i]!="")d[i]=l[i]-$i;l[i]=$i};if(s!=0){t++;sum+=s};s=0}END{print (sum/t)}'

Comment: `awk '/^P/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){s+=d[i]*(l[i]-$i);if(l[i]!="")d[i]=l[i]-$i;l[i]=$i};if(s!=0)t++}END{print s/t}'`

Comment: I tried it several time but still get th same message: if(‌​s!=0)t++} ^ invalid char '�' in expression.thanks  the ^ sign points to s.

Comment: @amir Try to delete the some chars around `s` and print it again

Comment: awk: cmd. line:1: /^P/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){s+=d[i]*(l[i]-$i);if(l[i]!="")d[i]=l[i]-$i;l[i]=$i};if(‌​s!=0)t++}END{print s/t}                                ^ invalid char '�' in expression. this the message

Comment: @amir Try to print in all program text by hand (not copy/paste) char by char.